# How to send output messages from a .exe program with Java?

Tags: java, inputstream, exe, outputstream

Here is the situation:
I have a java application which executes another java application example.exe (example.exe has some System.out.println("...");)

I want to get the output Stream from example.exe so i tried with something like that:
(looks pretty standard)

```
final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("example.exe");

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                String line = "";
                try {
                    while((line = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        inputText = inputText + line;
                    }
                    System.out.println(inputText);
                } finally {
                    inputReader.close();
                }
            } catch(IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

I would like to get the output messages of example.exe but it doesn't work and i don"t understand why, i get one message but not the one from example.exe, probably from java or something else.

Comment: Does your other java program actually `flush()` what it writes to its standard output?

Comment: I think flush() is already done with System.out.println(...); no?
I tried with and without doing a flush() and it's the same, i can see the message in the java console when my application is started by eclipse but nothing with my file .exe!

Comment: What is the text that you do get?

Comment: Actually i don't get any text now so i don't know from where it was coming :/ I get nothing from my rcp application.